# AWS - DynamoDB - How to make CRUD method that have to get item from different table

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have to creade KitchenService class that include CRUD methods for some things like for example: meal, product, recipe etc.
Recipe class has field of product class so in save method I have to get product from ProductTable, but it doesn't works fine.

This is my save method in DatabaseController:

```
public <T> void save(T objectToSave) {
    logger.log("Saveing object " + objectToSave);
    getMapper().save(objectToSave);
    logger.log("Saved object " + objectToSave);
}
```

And this is how looks my addRecipe method:

```
public Recipe addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
    databaseController.save(recipe);
    logger.log("Item created");
    return recipe;
}
```

To test this I use this JSON:

```
{"id":null,"name":"test3","labels":["GLUTEN_FREE"],"author":{"name":"Plejer Annołn","id":"testID2"},"media":{"name":"heheszki","url":"http://blabla.pl","mediaType":"IMAGE"},"recipeElements":[{"product":{"id":"08a7d7f3-7138-443d-b585-b01e9cbdc031"},"weight":"100"}],"approved":false}
```

I wanted to get product with id 08a7d7f3-7138-443d-b585-b01e9cbdc031 from product table but it just added product id field in recipe table. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the Read Consistency you're using? Maybe in this case you are not working with the most up-to-date data. Try using Strongly Consistency Read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

Comment: Nope I think You don't understand my question. I have two tables in DynamoDB: Product and Recipe. When I want to fill the RecipeTable, I have to get product from ProductTable that id is xxxxxx. When I want to test my method (check my json) it only add field called productId but not put the name of product etc.